# Modal box conflict with css key frames

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, css-animations

I have created a modal box, and works fine! After, i resolve insert a fadeInUp effect, using css keyframes. But, after make this, the modal box lost the centered position.

Can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks in advance!

[Modal box with keyframe conflit DEMO](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/fhuJD)

[Original modal box DEMO](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/akHlq)

Comment: If my answer was the solution would you mind marking it as correct so I get some points? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your demo you added in a CSS animation which contained this:

```
keyframes fadeInUp {
     0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
     }
     100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

This overwrites your translate(-50%, -50%) which is set before the animation runs.

If you change it to:

```
keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }       100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

You get the same effect but you don't overwrite your centering offset!

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/sidonaldson/pen/pmsfg)