# Bootstrap modal backdrop not hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I did lazy load for main div (.dashboard). But modal is not displayed due to animation. Here is an example.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEraxK

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.dashboard {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in-out 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-delay: .25s;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dashboard">
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
  <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>


  <!-- Modal Button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Launch demo modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Modal Body</div>
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#   <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I guess it is due to the "animation-fill-mode" feature. When you delete this feature, animation does not work.

Comment: I don't think you've actually asked a question here I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the Button and the Modal DIV are coming from AJAX service?

Comment: Yes it comes with modal ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue. Try adding this to your stylesheet -

**UPDATED**

```
.modal {
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
```

Comment: This closes the backdrop. But I do not want that. The effects are still hidden.

Comment: @RamazanApaydın I've updated my post. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This prevents the "lazy load" thing you do.

Answer (score 0):

U need just change HTML structure. Move out block `<!-- Modal -->` beyond the borders of block `<div class="dashboard">`

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
        @keyframes fadeIn {
          from {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          to {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }

        .dashboard{
          opacity: 0;
          animation: fadeIn ease-in-out 1 ;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-duration: .5s;
          animation-delay: .25s;
          padding:100px;
        }
        </style>

        <div class="dashboard"> <!-- <<< Start dashboard DIV -->
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>
          <div>Lazy Content DIV</div>

          <!-- Modal Button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Launch demo modal</button>
        </div> <!-- <<< END dashboard DIV -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Modal Body</div>
         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#   <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the content is loaded with ajax. This is not possible. Already the goal is to hide the effects after Ajax

Comment: I just show where you have a problem. Also u can add callback function for AJAX after success load. Or add a duplicate for the trigger, or load a separate the DIV modal. In fact there are many ways to solve it

Comment: The main problem is that modal is affected by animation. Animation When I add the body tag, there is no solution. Normally, this should not happen. There is a smiler problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418634/modal-box-conflict-with-css-key-frames

Answer (score 0):

When using Animation and 3D Transforms to move or change an element, the element and its contents might be promoted to a “gpu layer”, so browser can render independently from the rest of the page and be composited in later. This isolates the rendering of the content so that the rest of the page doesn’t have to be re-rendered if the element’s transform is the only thing that changes between frames, and often provides significant speed benefits.

In your codepen example you can also reproduce the same behavior by just adding `will-change: transform;` to the `.dashboard` element. [Here is a codepen example](https://codepen.io/burakcalik/pen/XWbWdOE). Because `will-change` property informs the browser ahead of time of what kinds of changes you are likely to make to an element in order to allow the browser to optimize how it handles the element ahead of time. So browser creates a new gpu layer for your element.

As a result your dashboard element has its own "GPU layer", and browser can't render the backdrop element in between your dashboard and modal elements.

Here is a few solutions you can do:
- Move your modal outside the dashboard div.
- Move the backdrop layer inside your dashboard div.
- Remove the animation after it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click tap', '[data-toggle=modal]', function() {
    const t = $($(this).data('target')).first();
    if (t.is('.modal') && t.parent().closest('div').is('div')) {
      t.appendTo('body');
    }
  });
});
```

Places the modal as an immediate child of `body` (where it should be placed), the first time it is opened.

The placement only happens once for each modal, when and only when the modal is opened for the first time and only for that modal. Any and all bound events are kept.

Do note it works with multiple modals, individually. Targeting each modal is done via Bootstrap's own's modal-target attributes (which basically means: if the modal opens, the solution works for it).

See it [working](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/OJVJRRv).

---

Wrote it in jQuery as you seem to be using it. For anyone needing a jQuery free alternative (React Bootstrap, VueBootstrap, etc...) here goes vanilla:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.addEventListener('click', moveModal);
  document.addEventListener('tap', moveModal);

  function moveModal(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('[data-toggle=modal]')) {
      const t = event.target;
      if (t.parentElement.closest('div')) {
        const m = document.querySelector(t.dataset.target);
        if (m && m.tagName == 'DIV') {
          document.body.appendChild(m);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Only tested in Chrome, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work in any normal browser. If anyone finds an issue, do let me know.

---

Note: solution assumes modals are opened by clicking or tapping an element with a `data-target="modal"` attribute, also having a `data-target="someSelector"` attribute, where `document.querySelector(someSelector)` would return the modal.

If that's not the case, or not the only case, I can write a more general solution, once I have the list of all used methods of opening a modal (don't know them all).